# compare std::wstring type and represent of wstring literal in ChaiScript

Tags: wstring, chaiscript

I want to write ChaiScript code using std::wstring type like below c++ code.

```
#include <iostream>

int testfunc(std::wstring s, std::wstring t)
{
    if(s==t)
    {
        std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
    }

    if(s[1]==t[1])
    {
        std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
    }

    if(s==L"aaaa")
    {
        std::cout << "3" << std::endl;
    }

    if(s[1]==L'b')
    {
        std::cout << "4" << std::endl;
    }

    return 5;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << testfunc(std::wstring(L"abcd"), std::wstring(L"abbb"));

    return 0;
}

D:\TestWork\test_chaiscript>t6
2
4
5
```

To compare the instances of std::wstring type is good.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chaiscript/chaiscript.hpp>
#include <chaiscript/chaiscript_stdlib.hpp>
#include <chaiscript/dispatchkit/bootstrap_stl.hpp>

int main()
{
    chaiscript::ChaiScript chai(chaiscript::Std_Lib::library());

    chai.add(chaiscript::bootstrap::standard_library::string_type<std::wstring>("wstring"));

    std::cout << chai.eval<std::function<int (std::wstring, std::wstring)> >(
        "fun(s, t){"
        "   if(s==t){"
        "       print(\"1\");"
        "   }"
        "   return 3;"
        "}"
    )(std::wstring(L"abcd"), std::wstring(L"abaa"));

    return 0;
}

D:\TestWork\test_chaiscript>t5
3
```

To compare the instances of wchar_t type doesn't work.

Do the compare operator method must be added?

```
        "   if(s[1]==t[1]){"
        "       print(\"2\");"
        "   }"

D:\TestWork\test_chaiscript>t5
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'chaiscript::exception::eval_error'
  what():  Error: "Error with numeric operator calling: =="
```

To compare the instance of std::wstring type with the literal of string type doesn't work.
I cannot input the literal of wstring type.

Is it possible to input the literal of wstring type in ChaiScript?

```
        "   if(s==\"aaaa\"){"
        "       print(\"2\");"
        "   }"

D:\TestWork\test_chaiscript>t5
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'chaiscript::exception::eval_error'
  what():  Error: "Can not find appropriate '==' operator." With parameters: (wstring, const string)
```

To compare the instance of wchar_t type with the literal of wchar_t type doesn't work.
I cannot input the literal of wchat_t type.

Is it possible to input the literal of wchat_t type in ChaiScript?

```
        "   if(s[1]=='b'){"
        "       print(\"2\");"
        "   }"

D:\TestWork\test_chaiscript>t5
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'chaiscript::exception::eval_error'
  what():  Error: "Error with numeric operator calling: =="
```

Comment: In the future, please edit your question when providing further information rather than "answering" the question, as it makes information difficult to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to tell ChaiScript something about `wchar_t`, such as the `==` operator. For example:

```
chai.add(
  chaiscript::fun<bool (wchar_t, wchar_t)>(
    [](wchar_t lhs, wchar_t rhs) { return lhs == rhs; }
  ), "=="
);
```

Comment: please read below my reply. I think that the native support wchar_t need in ChaiScript.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the native support wchar_t need in ChaiScript.

"Error with numeric operator calling: " exception is generated in chaiscript_eval.hpp.

If the type of variable is arithmetic, Boxed_Number::do_oper() is called.

```
// chaiscript_eval.hpp, line 98
if (t_oper != Operators::invalid && t_lhs.get_type_info().is_arithmetic() && t_rhs.get_type_info().is_arithmetic())
{
  // If it's an arithmetic operation we want to short circuit dispatch
  try{
    return Boxed_Number::do_oper(t_oper, t_lhs, t_rhs);
  } catch (const chaiscript::exception::arithmetic_error &) {
    throw;
  } catch (...) {
    throw exception::eval_error("Error with numeric operator calling: " + t_oper_string);
  }
} else {
```

It seems to use std::is_arithmetic to determine whether arithmetic type or not.

```
// type_info.hpp, 133 line
struct Get_Type_Info
{
    typedef T type;

     static Type_Info get()
    {
      return Type_Info(std::is_const<typename std::remove_pointer<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::type>::value, std::is_reference<T>::value, std::is_pointer<T>::value, 
          std::is_void<T>::value,
          std::is_arithmetic<T>::value && !std::is_same<typename std::remove_const<T>::type, bool>::value,
          &typeid(T), 
          &typeid(typename Bare_Type<T>::type));
    }
};
```

wchat_t is the arithmetic type.

```
std::cout << std::is_arithmetic<wchar_t>::value << std::endl;
std::cout << std::is_arithmetic<std::string>::value << std::endl;

D:\TestWork\test_chaiscript>t5.exe
1
0
```

If the type is arithmetic, oper() method for Boxed_Value is called.
But, wchar_t type is not supported in oper() method.

```
// boxed_number.hpp, 295 line
inline static Boxed_Value oper(Operators::Opers t_oper, const Boxed_Value &t_lhs, const Boxed_Value &t_rhs)
{
  const Type_Info &inp_ = t_lhs.get_type_info();

  if (inp_ == typeid(int)) {
    return oper_rhs<int>(t_oper, t_lhs, t_rhs);
  } else if (inp_ == typeid(double)) {
    return oper_rhs<double>(t_oper, t_lhs, t_rhs);
  } else if (inp_ == typeid(long double)) {
    return oper_rhs<long double>(t_oper, t_lhs, t_rhs);
  } else if (inp_ == typeid(float)) {
    return oper_rhs<float>(t_oper, t_lhs, t_rhs);
  } else if (inp_ == typeid(char)) {
    return oper_rhs<char>(t_oper, t_lhs, t_rhs);
  } else if (inp_ == typeid(unsigned int)) {
    return oper_rhs<unsigned int>(t_oper, t_lhs, t_rhs);
  } else if (inp_ == typeid(long)) {
    return oper_rhs<long>(t_oper, t_lhs, t_rhs);
  } else if (inp_ == typeid(unsigned long)) {
    return oper_rhs<unsigned long>(t_oper, t_lhs, t_rhs);
  } else if (inp_ == typeid(std::int8_t)) {
    return oper_rhs<std::int8_t>(t_oper, t_lhs, t_rhs);
  } else if (inp_ == typeid(std::int16_t)) {
    return oper_rhs<std::int16_t>(t_oper, t_lhs, t_rhs);
  } else if (inp_ == typeid(std::int32_t)) {
    return oper_rhs<std::int32_t>(t_oper, t_lhs, t_rhs);
  } else if (inp_ == typeid(std::int64_t)) {
    return oper_rhs<std::int64_t>(t_oper, t_lhs, t_rhs);
  } else if (inp_ == typeid(std::uint8_t)) {
    return oper_rhs<std::uint8_t>(t_oper, t_lhs, t_rhs);
  } else if (inp_ == typeid(std::uint16_t)) {
    return oper_rhs<std::uint16_t>(t_oper, t_lhs, t_rhs);
  } else if (inp_ == typeid(std::uint32_t)) {
    return oper_rhs<std::uint32_t>(t_oper, t_lhs, t_rhs);
  } else if (inp_ == typeid(std::uint64_t)) {
    return oper_rhs<std::uint64_t>(t_oper, t_lhs, t_rhs);
  } else  {
    throw chaiscript::detail::exception::bad_any_cast();
  }
}
```

I add the code to support wchar_t type like below in all place used inp == typeid(char).

```
} else if (inp_ == typeid(char)) {
    return go<LHS, char>(t_oper, t_lhs, t_rhs);
} else if (inp_ == typeid(wchar_t)) {
    return go<LHS, wchar_t>(t_oper, t_lhs, t_rhs);
} else if (inp_ == typeid(unsigned int)) {
```

My test code works well.

```
std::cout << chai.eval<std::function<int (wchar_t a, wchar_t b)> >(
    "fun(a, b){"
    "   if(a==b){"
    "       print(\"2\");"
    "   }"
    "   return 3;"
    "}"
)(wchar_t(L'a'), wchar_t(L'a'));

D:\TestWork\test_chaiscript>t5.exe
2
3
```